# How to Get a List of Logged in Users?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, auth0

I don't know how to narrow down this question further: We are using Auth0 and WebApi 2. I need to display a list of all users who are currently logged in. More specifically, Auth0 issues a token, this token is then sent with every request to our WebApi. I imagine, I need to write the token and the associated id to the database every time a request is made to any controller with the specific token? Can someone give me a general idea of whether or not I am on the right path here or what I should be reading?

Auth0 docs are of little help, since this seems to be an unusual requirement. Same with: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

I am not concerned about clientside. Just need the way to go on the server.

Edit: I added another part to this question in the comments: I would also like to know how to revoke tokens, effective immediately. To understand this, I believe I need to understand exactly how the backend verifies the token sent by the front end, and whether or not Auth0's server gets called for this at all.

Comment: Usually you use an authentication module which handles that aspect and places the pertinent details into a shared location where your logic can access them.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/sequence-diagrams this is the chain of events - from what I understand, it doesn't get saved anywhere, it just verifies if the user is authorized to perform the action, and that's that. (API isn't hit at all until Auth0 has issued a token and user makes some API call).

Comment: So, I would like to clarify - the answer is "There is some magical magic that Auth0 should probably provide, maybe does or doesn't?" I am not being sarcastic and appreciate any help, but it seems to me that there should be some way to react to the API being hit and get the token from there.

Comment: See if Auth0 supports OAuth and if so there are a lot of modules available that link up MVC and OAuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Developer Advocate at Auth0. Let me see if I can help you out :).

The whole idea of having an API that just checks the JWT is to have a Stateless API. Being "logged in" doesn't really exist in concept. All JWTs expire at some point in time, and that's what checked when you call an API.

Therefore, what I suggest is the following:

Every time you get an API call you save the JWT somewhere on memory. Then, we need to get logged in users, you just grab all the JWTs that you have on those list, and show the not expired ones as "logged in". Also, you should have a cron that goes every 5 minutes over the list and which cleans expires JWTs. It's not really "logged in" users, but I think it's close enough.

Would that work?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply mgonto. I considered something similar as a potential solution, and it's good to see you confirm it. However, there is another issue - the project has a bit of a weird requirement: we need to be able to get a list of all users with current access (let's consider this solved) and force them out of the system (individually), effective immediately. From what I understand (and this is critical), once Auth0 ISSUES the token, Auth0 is NOT involved in checking it. I.e. the client has the token (after getting it from Auth0) and sends it with requests...

Comment: ...Our WebAPI/OWIN/whatever backend receives the request, checks the token for validity (WITHOUT calling Auth0's server) and decided whether or not the token is valid. If that's the case, I don't understand what blacklisting a token does (https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/10/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/). If I am wrong, and Auth0 is involved in CHECKING the token, then this whole thing just got a lot easier since I can just make an API call to blacklist it. Thanks again for any help, I will check this throughout the day tomorrow.

Comment: Hey, you're right. The JWT is yours. In order to log them out, you'd have to store in your DB one ID per JWT that you receive so that you can blacklist them, and then before letting the user in with the middleware, you have to check that the JWT isn't blacklisted on that DB.